# Develop a WebService and consume it using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web-services, visual-studio-2012

i have no knowledge on this topic but need to accomplish this to save my job. please help me. I need to develop a basic web-service in visual studio 2012 and need to consume it using JavaScript.

Comment: That is a question that can't be answered in a few sentences. Take a look at this to get you started: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Comment: thanks for that. can you give me a basic example like addition of two numbers through web service and then consume it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but giving you a few lines of code won't help you on your problem. First you need to understand the basics of webservices. There's a ton of tutorials an articles on the internet about this topic. Try googling "c# web api" for your serverside code. For consuming webservices with javascript I would recommend using a framework like jquery. But in the end, you'll have to dig into this yourself to understand and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be what you are looking for? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398995%28v=vs.90%29.aspx